# multiple dependency injection problem

Tags: magento2, module, dependency-injection, di

I try to override some core files and in my custom module I injected the dependencies like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart"
                type="MyVendor\Custom\CustomerData\Cart" />
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\CustomerData\CheckoutTotalsJsLayoutDataProvider"
                type="MyVendor\Custom\CustomerData\CheckoutTotalsJsLayoutDataProvider" />
</config>
```

the second one is getting executed but the first does not seems to use the requested file.If set a var_dump in my override file no output is generated

Answer (score 0):

Change below code:

```
 <preference for="Magento\Tax\CustomerData\CheckoutTotalsJsLayoutDataProvider"
                type="MyVendor\Custom\CustomerData\CheckoutTotalsJsLayoutDataProvider" />
```

to:

```
<type name="MyVendor\Custom\CustomerData\CheckoutTotalsJsLayoutDataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayoutDataProvidersObject" xsi:type="object">Magento\Tax\CustomerData\CheckoutTotalsJsLayoutDataProvider</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Comment: thanks I tried but does not make any effect. Can you explain what brings different this snippet than the other one?